# Manually decrementing or aborting ajax requests with automation

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, selenium

I have some code that is running some automation tests to exercise the UI aspect of a product. I am faking some server responses using sinon.js, and using selenium to drive the UI. In some cases I need to wait for multiple ajax connections to complete (so the UI can render). So I have a wait for connections count to be 0.

```
 // AjaxHelper.cs
 wait.Until(d=> (bool)this.InvokeScript("return $ === undefined || $.active === 0 || $.ajax ===undefined || $.ajax.active === 0;"));
```

In another case I would like to NOT wait for connections to complete. I am looking for some kind of work around to either kill all active connections or decrement the connection count. I would like to implement this where the http response is mocked. I can easily capture the number of active connections.

```
// Server.cs
public void PopRequestQueue()
{
   this.LoadSinon();
   this.StartFakingServer();
   long activeConnections = (long)InvokeScript("return $.active;");
   if(activeConnections >= 1)
   {
      // kill those connections or decrement the count
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

turns out I can decrement the number of active connections by using

```
--jQuery.active;
```